# Instruct sbt dependencies processor to only update *missing* dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

Consider a project with many many dependencies. We add more dependencies- often one at a time - on a regular basis.

When a single dependency is added we have to wait minutes while `sbt` goes and re-verifies all of the *existing* libraries/dependencies.

is there a way to instruct `sbt` to "trust us" that the existing dependencies were valid - and just go fetch the *missing* ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable [cached resolution](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cached-Resolution.html) in your build.sbt:

```
updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)
```

For most project, using [Coursier](https://github.com/coursier/coursier#sbt-plugin) as an alternative to the built-in ivy resolution gives significant speedups in this area. Enable it with the setting:

```
addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "1.0.0-RC2")
```

Comment: Great Thanks for both of those options!

Comment: oh - another detail: What about for SNAPSHOT versions: is there an additional trick for saying "Yes, I know snapshots were supposed to be downloaded but maybe not this time"

Comment: you could use `set offline := true`, but that might not be what you want overall. I think it was also possible to modify the time sbt goes between checking snapshots somehow